# How to merge multiple Columns into MapType in Spark?

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

Assume I have DataFrame like this

```
val df = Seq((1, 2), (3, 4)).toDF("a", "b")
df.show()

+---+---+
|  a|  b|
+---+---+
|  1|  2|
|  3|  4|
+---+---+
```

I want to merge the 2 columns into one column with `MapType` so to be similar to this:

```
+----------+
|params    |
+----------+
|a->1, b->2|
|a->3, b->4|
+----------+
```

How can I do that?

Answer (score 1):

We can also generate map expression on all columns of dataframe using **`.map`** and **`.mkString`**

Then pass the expression in **`.selectExpr`** clause.

```
//Sample data
df.show()
//+---+----+
//| id|name|
//+---+----+
//|  1|   a|
//|  2|   b|
//+---+----+

//generate map expr on all columns of dataframe
val map_expr=df.columns.map( v => s""""$v",$v""").mkString("map(",",",")as params")

//pass the map_expr to selectExpr to get required output field.
df.selectExpr(s"$map_expr").show()

//+--------------------+
//|              params|
//+--------------------+
//|[id -> 1, name -> a]|
//|[id -> 2, name -> b]|
//+--------------------+
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure this is the best way to do it or not, but I was able to do it using `functions.map`

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions

def columnsToMap(name: String, columns: Column*): Column = {
  val columnsWithNames = columns.flatMap(column => Seq(lit(column.toString()), column))
  functions.map(columnsWithNames:_*).as(name)
}

val m = df.select(columnsToMap("params", df("a"), df("b")))
m.show()
+----------------+
|          params|
+----------------+
|[a -> 1, b -> 2]|
|[a -> 3, b -> 4]|
+----------------+
```